# WPF & Video processing by frame

Tags: wpf, image-processing, webcam, video-processing

can any one give me sample on how to access webcam in WPF and process it frame by frmae for video processing ,in faster way?
on each frame i have to find objects for further image processing

Answer (score 0):

Use [WPFMediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) (open source project) and use the control

```
WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls.VideoCaptureElement
```

Just set its attribute `VideoCaptureDevice`

```
myVideoCaptureElementcontrol.VideoCaptureDevice = MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices[0];
```

0 is the index of the video input device.